# Making a random number that's a multiple of 10

Tags: javascript, math, random

I'm looking to create a random number between two ranges that is a multiple of 10.

For example, if I fed the function the parameters `0, 100` it would return one of these numbers:

```
0, 10, 20, 30, 40, 50, 60, 70, 80, 90, 100
```

but nothing like `63` or `55`.

And yes I'm aware this defeats the point of true "randomness", but I just need a quick easy way to get a number that's a multiple of 10 between two ranges.

Thanks. :)

Comment: What happens if you pick a random integer number and multiply that by 10?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I guess it can help:

```
var randomnumber=Math.floor(Math.random()*11)*10
```

Comment: This is the only solution (until now) that gives the correct range.

Comment: These numbers do not respect the range

Answer (score 7):

it's just one line:

```
function rand_10(min, max){
    return Math.round((Math.random()*(max-min)+min)/10)*10;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
var a = 67;
var b = 124;
var lo = a + 10 - (a % 10) 
var hi = b - (b % 10)
var r = lo + 10 * parseInt(Math.random() * ((hi - lo)/10 + 1));
```

Answer (score 1):

```
function rand(maxNum, factorial) { 
    return Math.floor(Math.floor(Math.random() * (maxNum + factorial)) / factorial) * factorial; 
};
```

Takes two parameter

- `maxNum` Maximum number to be generated in random
- `factorial` The factorial/incremental number

  1. multiplies the random number generated to the maxNum.
  2. Rounds down the result.
  3. Divides by the factorial.
  4. Rounds down the result.
  5. then multiplies again by the factorial.

Comment: plz do explain your answer too

Answer (score 0):

Use a normal random number function like [this one](http://www.naden.de/blog/zufallszahlen-in-javascript-mit-mathrandom):

```
function GetRandom( min, max ) {
    if( min > max ) {
        return( -1 );
    }
    if( min == max ) {
        return( min );
    }

    return( min + parseInt( Math.random() * ( max-min+1 ) ) );
}
```

As this will only return integers ("multiples of 1"), you can multiply by 10 and get only multiples of 10.

```
randomNumberMultipleOfTen = GetRandom(0,10) * 10;
```

Of course you can merge both into one function if you want to, I'll leave this as an exercise to you.

Answer (score 0):

This seems to do the work

```
Math.floor(Math.random() * 10) * 10
```

If you modify that a little you can easily make it between any two numbers.

Answer (score -1):

1. Take the difference of the two parameters.
2. Divide the difference by 10.
3. Generate a random number from 0 to the result of the division.
4. Multiply that by 10.

Comment: I don't think this works. The number of multiples of 10 in an interval doesn't just depend on the difference of the endpoints of that interval. For example, the interval `(18, 32)` contains two multiples of 10, while the interval `(22, 36)` has the same size, so gives the same difference in step 1, but contains only a single multiple of 10. Also, there's an addition needed after step 4. Else e.g. when applying the suggested algorithm to the interval `(200, 300)`, results will always be in `[0, 100]` instead.